# dl dt and dd to display birthday CSS

Tags: html, css

I would like to display day, month and year in form using `dl`, `dt` and `dd`.

I would like this to present like this :

```
BIRTHDAY

    day month year
    in1 in2   in3
```

Where `in*` is the input of given type, it shouldnt matter.

How should the css should look like to accomplish this?

My current code is:

```
<dl>
  <dt>day</dt>
  <dd>myInput<dd>

  <dt>month</dt>
  <dd>myInput2</dd>

  <dt>year</dt>
  <dd>myInput3</dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: Question is how to set css to do that

Comment: You're requesting us to code for you. This site is for questions, not requests. What have you tried? What isn't working?

Comment: <dl> stands for Definition List. What you want looks like a table. So why don't you use the proper <table> element for that?

Comment: Because tables are cursed. You can't use them, even for tables or calendars. You must use `<div>` tags, tons of CSS, and an endless supply of coffee to keep you awake for the hours it takes you to replicate table behavior without `<table>` tags. Then you figure out IE doesn't work with your site...

Comment: I dunno... It sounds like a bunch of `div` tags.

Comment: Tables are not cursed. You must use tables to represent that structure, because their use is exactly intended for that goal. You shall not use tables as a div, to create containers, like many people did some years ago. But to represent data in a table, you should use the...table element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in the need of a table, not definition lists (`<dl>` tag pairs). People constantly neglect using tables, even though they are completely appropriate (and originally made) for the job.

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="birthday">
    <span class="title">Birthday</span>

    <table>
        <th>
            <td>Day</td> <td>Month</td> <td>Year</td>
        </th>

        <tr>
            <td>25</td> <td>1</td> <td>1902</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**The CSS:**

```
.birthday
{
    padding-left: 30px;
}

.birthday .title
{
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 20px;

    margin-left: -30px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.birthday table tr td
{
    min-width: 50px;
}
```

**Live Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/Blender/5rhLd/

Comment: If you going to use a table, please make the top row `th`s not `td`s.

Comment: *That's* what you use for table heads... Thanks @Alohci!

Answer (score -1):

If you know how to use [dl, dt and dd](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_dd_test).

The only problem is how to separate the six dd into two lines

In css, you can set dd float, and the six dd will show in the same line.

Then, use `<br />` to move in1 in2   in3 to the second line

Comment: I donbt understand to be honest :)